# infimum and supremum of subsets question

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

Let $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{+}$ such that B is non-empty.
consider $B^{-1} = \left \{b^{-1} : b\in B \right \}$.
Show that if $B^{-1}$ is unbounded from above, then $\inf\left(B\right)=0$

How can i prove that? tnx!

Comment: Prove the contrapositive.

Comment: i don't get you @GitGud

Comment: Do you know what the contrapositive of a statement is?

Answer (score 0):

B^−1 is unbounded from above hence for every n in N, there exist b in B such that 1/b>n then 1/n > b for every n. Hence inf B =0(note infimum exist because B bounded below by 0)

Comment: Otherwise prove contrapositive as pointed out by Git Gud

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Timbuc thanks a lot for reference

Comment: @Sushil why "Hence inf B =0" ? why for example is not 4 or 7.5 for example? why it has to be 0?

Comment: @user2637293 we proved there is b such that b < 1/2 so inf has to be less than 1/2 and this we proved for all 1/n hence follow argument. The only problem is inf does not exist which does not arise because of least upper bound axiom

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if not, then $\inf B =\delta>0$. Therefore
$$
b \geq \delta>0
$$
for every $b \in B$, and hence$ \frac{1}{b} \leq \frac{1}{\delta}$. In particular, $B^{-1}$ is bounded from above. Contradiction.

Comment: I think you have to interchange $\;B\leftrightarrow B^{-1}\;$ , so that $$\forall b\in B\;,\;\;b\ge\delta >0\implies b^{-1}=\frac1b\le \frac1\delta\implies B^{-1}\;\;$$ is bounded above, contradiction.